# school google account on my school computer

Tags: account-security, google

I'm logged into my school Google account at home. Can what I search at home on my own computer be checked by my school even though I'm not using their computers?

Comment: Your title says that you are logged into your **school computer**. Is that true? Are you asking if your school can track what you search  on your personal Google account on your personal computer when you are logged into your school Google account on the school computer?

Comment: assuming the "school Google account" is one that they have access to, and one that they would log into from time to time because your online activity is very interesting to them, the answer is yes... in that they will know as much as you would logging into your own account.  they/you won't have access to bookmarks or cookies that are stored on the other machine but can infer certain things by ads displayed and auto-suggestions in the search bar.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, **Google search terms and history is not public** and it is not accessible to everyone or your organization who issues you an email account until you have a policy or agreement. But if you synchronize your searches and bookmarks across your all devices then the school account branch (Which holds and manages passwords) can access it.

Google has some strong policies against this. ([Privacy policies](https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en-US))

> If you have a school account like "somename@xyz.school.edu" (just an
>   example)

1. They can read your Inbox/ messages and emails.
2. They can't watch search history and bookmarks if you are not syncing your data with an account in browser.

**That's why I will recommend you to use the personal accounts and minimize the use of school/ organizational emails when not needed.**

Comment: From the phrasing of the question, it's a Google account provided by the school. This answer is wrong, if that's true.

Comment: I was assuming they use Google. But you are right, I want to request the person to specify which type of account is provided by the school. like is it's Google or some other company so that I can modify my answer accordingly.